# Remove class of a child by classname

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, removeclass

I would like to remove onclick all class of some elements and then to add the class selected to the element which was clicked.

Below is my html code

```
<div class="attribute_list">
    <div class="taille_div">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Taille :
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio radio_taille" name="group_1" value="1" checked="checked" />
                    <span class="taille_span">S</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio radio_taille" name="group_1" value="2" />
                    <span class="taille_span">M</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio radio_taille" name="group_1" value="3" />
                    <span class="taille_span">L</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio radio_taille" name="group_1" value="4" />
                    <span class="taille_span">XL</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Then I have this jquery on ready and it works for the part which add a class to the closest span but not for the first part which removes the class of the selected elements

```
$('.taille_span').click(function(){
    $('#taille_div > ul > li >label > span').removeClass('radio_taille_selected')
    $(this).closest('span').addClass('radio_taille_checked')
})
```

I don't know how to remove the class of the span that contains the class taille_span

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Your HTML is not well writing  ( closed tags without open )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over complicating it.... just look for the class itself

```
$('.taille_span').click(function(){
    $('.radio_taille_selected').removeClass('radio_taille_selected')
    $(this).addClass('radio_taille_checked');
});
```

That being said there is also a mismatch of class names being used `'radio_taille_selected'` vs `'radio_taille_checked'` so it's not entirely  clear which is correct